# Java war file wrongly (?) detected as an invalid zip file

Tags: linux, java, zip, maven

To do a test, I have to add a `jar` file into a `Java` *war* file I've created with `Maven`. The *war* file works itself fine.

To insert my `lz4-java-1.6.0.jar` into `application-metier-et-gestion.war` on internal zip folder `/WEB-INF/lib`, I use this command :

`zip -b WEB-INF/lib application-metier-et-gestion.war lz4-java-1.6.0.jar`

But I receive that error message :
*zip warning: expected 354 entries but found 84*
*zip error: Zip file structure invalid (application-metier-et-gestion.war)*

I can do and redo `mvn clean install` it will always create a runnable war that seems perfect to me, but that `zip` declares invalid. Who is wrong ?

- I case `zip` would be going wrong, what is the workaround to do what I want ? Is there a way through another tool ? `tar` ?
- I case `Maven` would be going wrong and create a bad war file each time, how to detect the part it is creating wrongly ?

Answer (score 0):

right click the war file ,rename the file extension war into zip

example :

test.war -> test.zip

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you tried to add an additional library to the archive.
JAR files and WAR files are plain ZIP files. There is only one rule you have to obey, library files must not be compressed.
If you want to add JAR files to a JAR or WAR file, disable compression for the specific file to be added.